# Download file generated in MS Teams tab

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I am building a MS Teams app, that should run in a tab. How can I let the user download a file in the app that was generated in the client? In a normal web app running outside Teams I am able to use the saveAs function in https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js, but it doesn't seem to work inside a Teams tab.

I also have tried using the microsoftTeams.openFilePreview(...) function with objectUrl set to a data Url, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to view/download a pdf file in Teams Tab, Make sure your URL is an iframe.

Comment: What do you mean "Make sure your URL is an iframe"? Should I create an iframe and set the src attribute to my data URL?

Comment: Yes, When user will click on download button it will open in teamsFileViewer there you can download if data URL is an iframe

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with below code,

var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");

```
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
    ifrm.style.width = "640px";
    ifrm.style.height = "480px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
    return ifrm;
```

I have implemented and tested the above code, it is working as expected.

Comment: Is actionData_URL in your code meant to be my Data url (an example could be data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXB....)? And what is prefix? Is this supposed to work with microsoftTeams.openFilePreview?

Comment: Example:
new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction() {​​ Title = actionText, Url = new Uri(GetFileViewerURL("Your File URL here", "pptx")) }​​;

Comment: My teams app is a SPA using the @microsoft/teams-js package (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-latest) so it doesn't have access to the C# classes you are refering to. Also could you let me know if the actionData_URL you mention is a data url on the format data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXB...?

Comment: Could you please try with below code,

var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");

        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
        return ifrm;

I have implemented and tested the above code, it is working as expected.

Please take the code from answer section.

Comment: The above code also works in my code, but if I replace the url to the dummy pdf with the data url that I need to download it doesn't work. The data url is on the form data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQ...I suspect that it is because I can only use url domains in iframe src that are listed in the manifest files validDomains section. Is there a solution that will work with Data urls?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the solution with iframe to work with a data url, but this solution works:

```
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
```

where url is a data url (for instance data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQ...), and filename is the name of the file to download.

Comment: It does not work for me. Are you sure you have tested it with Microsoft Teams, on a mobile device (android or iOS)??

Comment: I haven't tested it on a mobile device, so I don't know if it works on those platforms.

Comment: Hello from 2022, it doesn't work on Android or iOS. :(